# Where to download Azure SDK 2.7.1 needed to deploy Sitecore Azure 8.1?

Tags: configuration, azure

We are building a development environment for Sitecore 8.1 Update 1 with Sitecore Azure 8.1.

Since Sitecore Azure requires Azure SDK 2.7.1 to be deployed, I am having such a bad day trying to figure out where to download Azure SDK 2.7.1 installer. It is quite old version so Microsoft is now redirecting all download pages to the download page for latest Azure SDK version.

I went to the download page for manual installation, but the page does not contain "WebToolsExtensionsVS2015.msi" so now there is no way to install Azure SDK 2.7.1.

Have anyone successfully installed Azure SDK 2.7.1 recently?
I am not sure if I consult with Sitecore Support for this question.

Comment: You can install everything you need for Microsoft Azure development using the Web Platform Installer. Try this link. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried that way but it seems the page for SDK 2.7.1 in Web Platform is now redirected to the latest version, 3.0.1.

Comment: Try this link azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads and click on Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried but the link also redirects to Azure SDK version 3.0.1...

Comment: Try this GitHub repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net as last resort :). Maybe you will find something in 2017 releases

Answer (score 1):

You can download it via Web platform Installer. That solves the problem for alternative to downloading `.msi` file.

[image]

However I find that there is no 2.7.1 available at the Web Platform Installer, It is either `3.0.1` or `2.9.6`. Because Azure SDK version 2.7.1 has **retired on April 3, 2017.**

**Download from Archives**

Even if you want to download the older versions (2.7.1), you can download it from the Microsoft Download Archives.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

Comment: Yeah I also got there too... It seems currently there is no way to find the installer for Azure SDK 2.7.1.